# How do I handle this initializer?

Tags: swift, initializer, deinit

Create a class called `Parent` with a `title` property and write an `init` and `deinit` method for your class.

Write a subclass called `Child`.

My problem is putting this into the code (call `super.init(title:)` and pass on the `title` parameter.

```
class Parent {
    let title: String

    init(title: String){
        self.title = title
        print("\(title) is initialized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(title) is being deinitialized.")
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    let subtitle: String
    init(subtitle: String){
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        // i'm supposed to call a super.init, how

        print("\(subtitle) is initialized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(subtitle) is being deinitialized.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your initializer for your `Child` take both a `title` and a `subtitle`, and then call `super.init(title: title)` in your `Child`'s initializer:

```
class Child: Parent {
    let subtitle: String
    init(title: String, subtitle: String){
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        super.init(title: title)

        print("\(subtitle) is initialized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(subtitle) is being deinitialized.")
    }
}
```

Then if you create a `Child` object and assign it to an *Optional* `Child` (i.e. `Child?`) you'll see both *initialized* messages:

```
var child: Child? = Child(title: "Star Wars: Episode VI", subtitle: "Return of the Jedi")
```

> Star Wars: Episode VI is initialized
>   Return of the Jedi is initialized

and then if you assign `nil` to your variable you'll see both *deinitialized* messages:

```
child = nil
```

> Return of the Jedi is being deinitialized.
>   Star Wars: Episode VI is being deinitialized.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing I forgot to put in "Create an optional var of type Child and assign a child object to it."

Comment: `var child: Child? = Child(title: "some title", subtitle: "some subtitle")`

Comment: Then if you follow that up with `child = nil`, you'll see both of your deinit messages.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't try but I think it could work this way. Let me know if it works.

```
class Child: Parent {
    let subtitle: String

    override init(title: String, subtitle:String) {
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        super.init(title)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to specify a type for `title` and `string`? This code doesn't compile for me.

Comment: Yeah, you right, i think i doesn't compile it has to be defined both as string